# Why is this corridor in Inferno called "Banana"?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, terminology

I was watching a recent replay of a CS:GO match. For some reason the casters kept talking about a team "*keeping great control of banana*". For example [at around 19:04 in this ESL video](https://youtu.be/vDvFsxfDlm4?t=1140). At first I thought I misheard, but then I checked various maps online, including this one:

[image: callouts on inferno]

And for sure, there it is: "**BANANA**".

*All* of the other callouts / names on this map make sense somehow. Is there some inside CS:GO joke that I'm missing here?

Why is it called "Banana"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The wall texture on the original Inferno (1.1/1.3) was yellow and the shape of the path was a banana.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer that predates even CS1.6, as 1.6 changed the colors of the walls to a very grayish-bluish color.

Comment: Isn't there also a slight curve to it in the modern version of Inferno? I feel like my visual memory of that area doesn't match what's depicted on the map.

Answer (score 11):

Because it's curved like a banana.

*(Some people online say it's because there's a yellow car, but this is incorrect - the same stretch was called 'banana' in CS 1.6, and there was no car on the map back then)*